# Nested loop extracting index values into new array

Tags: java

I am trying to extract specific index values from an array, and place them into a new array. The primary array values are as follows:

```
 int a[] = {7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7};
```

The call I am making to the method is as follows:

```
print(findAll (a,7));
print(findAll (a,2));
```

The method I am using is as follows:

```
public int[] findAll(int a[], int target)
    {
       int count = 0;
       int i = 0; 
       int index = 0;
       int spotIndex = 0;


       for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
          if (a[i] == target)
            count = count + 1;
            spotIndex = i;
        }        

        int result[] = new int[count];

        for (index = 0; index < count; index++) 
        {
            result[index] = spotIndex;
            index++;

        }
        return result;
    }
```

The results should be:

{0, 5}
{}

My results are below; if I change the target argument I get the same results.

{5, 0}
{}

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spotIndex` isn't serving the purpose you thought needed for.

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
      if (a[i] == target)
        count = count + 1;
        spotIndex = i;     // spotIndex comes in for loop but not in if condition.
                           // and this gets modified at every step in loop.
                           // simply assigning value of i to it.
}
```

Instead the logic should be -

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
      if (a[i] == target)
        count = count + 1;
}
```

`count` gives the number of times `target` is repeated. Now, create an array of size `count` to actually copy those element's index in to the array.

```
int result[] = new int[count];
int copyIndex = 0;
for (index = 0; index < a.length; index++) 
{
     if( a[index] == target )
     {
          result[copyIndex] = index ;
          ++copyIndex;  

          if( copyIndex == count )
              return result ;              
     }  
}
```

I don't see the use of this statement - `spotIndex = i;` in first loop.

**Note:** The logic assumes that search element( i.e., `target` ) is definitely present in the array. With slight modification though, we can return the indexes if element is present only.

Answer (score 1):

Small advice:

```
for (index = 0; index < count; index++) 
{
    result[index] = spotIndex;
    index++;
}
```

you index++ call double times. This is bad practice to use index in method scope, better is:

```
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) 
{
    result[index] = spotIndex;
}
```

Notice that you put spotIndex (the same value) in all result elements.

Why you don't use List?

```
public Integer[] findAll(int a[], int target) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == target) {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }       
    return result.toArray(new Integer[result.size()]);
}
```